# Why bootstrap modal removes my scroll bar after closing modal and anchoring to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal and and button inside it aside from the close button. So what I want is when I click the button, the modal will close and will navigate to the same page via anchor tag. This works but problem is the modal is removing or disabling the scroll bar. The modal thinks as if the modal is still open.

I have this:

```
$( "#silverB" ).click(function() {
  $("#myModal").hide();
  $(document.body).scrollTop($('#optin').offset().top);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not retire the `modal` using `.hide()`. Instead use this:

```
$("#myModal").modal("hide");
```

Because, bootstrap adds more classes to body (`.modal-open`) when the modal is opened. But when you "hide" the modal, they are not reset.

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options):

> `.modal('hide')`
>
> Manually hides a modal. Returns to the caller before the modal has actually been hidden (i.e. before the hidden.bs.modal event occurs).`

Comment: Thanks but when I do that. it comes back down. The anchor tag is in top. The button which triggers the modal is in the buttom. When I click the button below, the modal appears and I click the button inside the modal then the modal close and will anchor in top page the back to bottom again.

Comment: @Yassi Then please show us a working model. Do one thing. After calling `hide()`, add `$("body").removeClass("modal-open")`.

Comment: http://easyfuneralplans.com/form/create# there click the Silver Plans button and the modal will appear then click Get Quote then it should be anchored on top. But it goes down. Already done ur suggestion

Comment: @Yassi you have open tags and `<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>` added twice

Comment: @Yassi Gotcha... Oh, so it should go to top is it?

Comment: @Yassi Why do you have `<a>` inside `<button>`? That's a wrong code.

Comment: @Yassi, did you happen to check the site in firefox and try to reopen the modal after click on get quote? modal does open but instantly close again

Comment: @PraveenKumar I would suggest more simple solution, use data attribute to close modal `data-dismiss="modal"` on get quote button, get rid of click function and `modal('hide')` and use event `hidden.bs.modal` to scroll top once modal closed

Comment: @Shehary I am still not sure why the OP has used a `<a>` inside `<button>`!

Comment: I totally have no idea about <a> inside `<button>` and the way it looks, trying to make things unnecessarily complicated and yes as suggested in above comment, @Yassi use `data-dismiss="modal"` to close the modal get rid of click event and with modal hidden event `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {$(document.body).scrollTop($('#optin').offset().top);})` scroll will work, happen to be working with B.S so it's tested :).

Comment: @Shehary That might also cause the issue. Yeah, what you have given would work... `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96906/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-shehary).

Comment: @Shehary I fixed it already with your suggesstion . :)  works fine now. Never mind the <a> tag hehe it's just I'm having some trial and error. Thank u guys.